# UnexpectedValueException when create a log file in SLIM monolog

Tags: php, slim, monolog

I am on MAC and another computer with WINDOWS call to my API endpoints and I got the following error . (happen also when there are no logs)

```
fatal error: Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message 'The stream or file "/../logs/2018-01-15.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied' in .../vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php on line 107
```

1 How can I make sure the log will create a folder itself with full permission or change permission to existing one 
2 how do I catch UnexpectedValueException in SLIM ?
3. created a folder manually with full permission will solve the problem?
4. will windows-to windows  work properly ? maybe is it mac os permission issue ?

Comment: Now wait, the PHP file that handles the request, is it stored on your Mac or your Windows?

Comment: @MehdiBounya in My mac

Answer (score 0):

Use chmod -R 777 on the logs folder